# Optical audio input options for iMac Pro

Tags: audio, imac-pro

I will soon be upgrading from a 2014 Mac Mini to an iMac Pro. I am a little surprised to discover that the iMac Pro does not have a digital optical audio input (TOSLINK/SPDIF), which is something I've been relying on with the Mini for audio capture, for I have a piece of home studio equipment that only has an optical digital output.

I thought there might be an external USB-C audio capture device on the market instead, but a look through online stores doesn't offer any hobbyist-level solution (there is high-end pro audio gear that is way beyond my price bracket or needs).  A few devices do analogue input (such as the Griffin iMic and the Behringer Uca202), but that's not what I'm after; neither can do optical/digital input.

The search is hindered by all the output devices showing up from the same query, so perhaps I missed something. It seems like an obvious device to offer.

Has anyone solved this problem? What are my options?

Comment: Just a thought, but it may be worth you editing your question to include details of your studio equipment.

Comment: I didn't and I won't because I specifically cannot invite solutions that focus on alternatives to, or modifications of, that device. It is not an Apple device, and since this is Ask Different I want to keep the focus on a general solution for all iMac Pro users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a USB device that captures optical input.  I'm using a miniDSP USBstreamer B, and with the TOSLINK firmware installed it is doing the job perfectly with a clear signal and low latency.